# Laravel NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I began to study Laravel, I have this problem.

[image]

File: `project/app/Http/routes.php`

```
<?php

Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
```

In the directory project I do by terminal

```
php artisan make:controller PagesController
```

File: `project/app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function about() 
    {
        return("About");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter in apache configuration file and specify AllowOverride Yes on the directory where laravel still working

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing your `/` route in your provided image. Which is not defined in your routes.php file that's why you are getting this error.

Add

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return "hello world";
});
```

and then try this route: `192.168.1.101/laravel-p/public/`

**Note** you've explained the `about` route in your above code. So hit this route

```
`192.168.1.101/laravel-p/public/about`
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are accessing your / route in your provided image. Which is not
>   defined in your routes.php file that's why you are getting this error.
>
> Add
>
> Route::get('/', function() {
>       return "hello world"; });
>
> and then try this route: 192.168.1.101/laravel-p/public/
>
> Note you've explained the about route in your above code. So hit this
>   route
>
> `192.168.1.101/laravel-p/public/about`

Nothing..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUhBH.png)

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function() {
    return "hello world";
});

Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
```